# Iterating over a file in perl using for loop with perl

Tags: perl, file, iteration

If `for` returns a whole list of a file and then iterates over it, how can I skip file line without using `next` command ?

Well as like this with an array

```
my @lines = ('first line', 'second line', 'third line');
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#lines; $i++){
   print $lines[$i];
   $i++;
}
```

output: `first line`, `third line`;

Is it even possible to do the same with a file without pushing it into an array?

Comment: Describe the problem. Why you cannot use `next`? Why you cannot just read as usual (`while(defined(my $line = <$fh>))`) ?

Comment: I have a huge file, in some line it have to skip like 30 lines or even maybe i have to go back by some lines.. so `$i++` and `$i--` would help me a lot! I don't know the line number, so @Chankey's method wont work for me.

Comment: If you don't know line numbers then how will you know which lines to skip? Are you looking for something on the line, skipping based on a value in a previous line?

Comment: You should explain the *actual* problem you are trying to solve. The requirement to *"go back by some lines"* isn't part of the problem - it is a requirement of your chosen solution. Please show a sample of the file that you want to read and explain how you need to process it

Comment: Does [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) help? `Access the lines of a disk file via a Perl array` ... `The file is not loaded into memory, so this will work even for gigantic files.`

Comment: Tie::File is easy to use, but it will be surely be really slowly and memory hungry compared to proper solution. If only we knew what you were trying to do.

Comment: @LadyCygnus line number is not necesarry because im checking the line with regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I skip file line without using next command ?

With the code you have you can use a counter there and increment it after each line iteration and do something like

```
if($counter == 2){
#do nothing
}
else{
    print $lines[$i];
}
```

So in your code do

```
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#lines; $i++){
   if($i == 1){
      #do nothing
   }
   else{
      print $lines[$i];
   }
}
```

---

> Is it even possible to do the same with a file without pushing it into
>   an array?

Open file with a filehandle as

```
open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
```

Then read it line by line

```
while(my $line = <$fh>){
   #work on line, apply some condition here to skip. for eg
   if ($line =~ /sometext/){
       #skip it using next or empty if block etc.
   }
   else{
       #work on it
   }
}
```

Also see: [How can I skip lines when slurping a file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775882/how-can-i-skip-lines-when-slurping-a-file-in-perl)

Comment: You can iterate line by line using while loop and then there add checks to skip lines. You can use counter technique there also.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `$i++;` is to skip an element. The closest equivalent:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   print;

   # Skip a line.
   last if !defined($line = <$fh>);
}
```

It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you want to skip even lines, I'd go with

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   next if $. % 2 == 0;   # Skip even lines
   print;
}
```

Oh wait, you said no `next`.

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   if ($. % 2) {
      print;
   }
}
```

Comment: Curious why you're using explicit `== 1`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a huge file, in some line it have to skip like 30 lines or even maybe i have to go back by some lines.. aaand I don't know the line number, so @Chankey's method wont work for me.

You can read your file as usual and use `next` command freely:

```
open(my $fh, "filename") || die "Cant open file: $!";
while( defined(my $line = <$fh>) ) {
   next if $line =~ /blablabla/;
   #...
}
```

If you want to be able to return back to some line, i'd prefer to use an array with file offsets and make `seek` call when you need to. So, you never read whole file into memory and holding in-memory only "line number=>offset" array, which can be optimized different ways. Template can look like this:

```
my $curr_line=0;
my @offsets = (0); #0th line has offset 0
open(my $fh, "filename") || die "Cant open file: $!";
while( defined(my $line = <$fh>) ) {
   $offsets[++$curr_line] = tell($fh); #Save line-number => offset
   next if $line =~ /blablabla/;
   if( $line =~ /^return-line: (\d+)/ && $1>0 ) { #A logic which wants to go back to $1-th line
      $curr_line=$1-1;
      seek($fh, $offsets[$curr_line], 0);
      next;
   }
   #...
}
```